# Error on webservice and Basic Authentication

Tags: tomcat, basic-authentication

I know there are similar questions, but I've tried and can't find where the error is.

I want ot setup Basic authentication to access a webservice in tomcat, developing in netbeans 7.4

So the webservice is in the URL MyWebservice for example so I can get the WSDL if I browse to http://localhost:8084/MyWebservice?wsdl if there is not Authentication setup.

So I've put in tomcat-users.xml:

```
<role rolename="webservicerole"/>
<user username="wsuser" password="wspwd" roles="webservicerole"/>
```

And in the web.xml:

```
<security-constraint> 
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>MyWebservice</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/MyWebservice</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
    <role-name>wsuser</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint> 
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

Now if I browse to http://localhost:8084/MyWebservice I got a http 403 error, If I quit the Basic auth in web.xml I got a correct web page showing info about ports etc on the webservice url address.

What (sure obvious) error I can't view???

I'm pretty sure I did something similar with DIGEST authentication inside a directory sometime ago and it worked perfectly.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `rolename` is incorrect. It should be:

```
<auth-constraint>
   <role-name>webservicerole</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I was sure it was a silly fault but as long as I review the xml I cant find the error, grrrrr.  Thanks!!!